# How to get $a,b$ and $c$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm doing some exercises about calculus, and the exercise asked me to discover the values of $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Be the function $y = x^2 + ax + b$ and the function $y = cx - x^2$ have the same tangent in the point $(3,3)$, what the values to $a$, $b$ and $c$ ?

My first idea is to get the rate function from above functions:

$y' = 2x + a$

$y' = -2x + c$

And if the tangent point is common in both functions, I have a equality: $2x + a = -2x + c$

It give to me: $a = c-12$ or $c = a+12$.

But I've no idea how to proceed to discover the values. Could you give to me some help ?

Comment: Also, both curves must pass through the point $(3,3)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the functions to have the same tangent at the point $(3,3)$. The tangent of the function at point $x=x_0$ is determined by two things: It goes through the point $(x_0,f(x_0))$ and it has the slope $f'(x_0)$

In order for two functions, $f$ and $g$, to have the same tangent at point $(x_0,y_0)$, two things must hold:

1. Graphs of both functions must contain the point $(x_0,y_0)$
2. The derivatives of both functions *at the point* $x=x_0$ must be the same.

Comment: The OP did substitute $x=3$ in both derivative expressions, so the working is fine that far.

Comment: Ok, but it give to me, a = -6 ans c = 6 ? Sorry the ignorance.

Comment: How did you get $a=-6$ and $c=6$? Please also write the equations that you derived, not just the results.

Comment: WoW, sorry.. rsrsr
y' = 2x + a and y' = -2x + c.
y' = 2*3 + a and y' = -2*3 + c

Comment: @mastergoo No need to be sorry, just write down what you got so we can inspect where you might have gone wrong. What are the equations you got so far?

Comment: 5xum, I'm using the idea of point = (x0, f(x0)) equals to both functions, but I cant undertand how to find the values yet.. Can you give-me another hint ? :(

Comment: Not yet. What equation do you get when you set both functions to have the same value at $x_0=3$? If you will not write a single equation, I refuse to give more hints.:P

Comment: To be equal, let $f(x) = x² + ax + b$, g(x) = $cx−x²$. So f(3) = g(3). I have 3c - 9 = 9 + 3a + b, Right ?

Comment: Yes. But you also know that $f(3)=3$, since you want $f$ to pass through $(3,3)$. And you know the same for $g$.

Comment: Woooooooooooowwww.... $g(x) = 3$, so $3 = 3c-9$, c = 4. :D

Comment: Well done. Now, it should be easier to find $a$ and $b$ from the remaining $2$ equations.

Comment: @5xum, yes I guess will be easy, thank you a lot!!!!!!

Comment: You are welcome. You did nost of the work yourself, anyway:P

Comment: Hahah just to done: a = -8, b = 18, c = 4

Comment: Looks good to me.